# Find definition of CSS class in external stylesheet

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome's Development Tools to inspect an element from a web page. Suppose it shows something like:

```
<div class="some-class">
```

Assuming `some-class` is defined in an external style sheet, what is the *simplest* way to find the style sheet(s) that define `some-class`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're using the Chrome inspector (right click page, inspect element), highlight the line and look to the right. It should show the CSS class and any rules that are used, and a link to the CSS file.

[image]

Comment: So if there is no class shown on the right, the class simply doesn't exist?

Comment: @tronman if it's not listed, it sounds like the class has no actual CSS rules associated with it.

Comment: You've confirmed what I have always thought to be true, but I have some CSS that is *not* showing the class name on the right, and I know it is defined. If I delete the class manually using the dev tool, the item is re-styled. Maybe it's because we're using AngularJS in an iframe... maybe that throws off the dev tools.

Comment: Ah... the problem is the class didn't have any styles that were affecting the parent but its children, so Chrome would only show the class when you highlighted the children.